# Ajustar tamaño y posicion de imagen en power point

Tags: vba

Estimados estoy creando una macro para poder ajustar 2 imagenes en una diapositiva de power point.

Estoy teniendo problemas para poder llamar a la imagen 1 ejemplo foto1.jpg y esta se ajuste de acuerdo al parametro 1 (mi_imagen) y foto2.jpg se adecuea al siguiente parametro (mi_imagen2)

El codigo es el siguiente

```
    Sub ajustar()
Dim mi_imagen As Shape
Dim mi_imagen2 As Shape

Set mi_imagen = ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(1)

With mi_imagen
        .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Left = 450
        .Top = 70
        .Width = 490
        .Height = 335
End With
Set mi_imagen2 = ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(2)

With mi_imagen2
        .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Left = 10
        .Top = 70
        .Width = 430
        .Height = 335

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerPoint no lo tengo dominado, no es algo con lo que suela trabajar

para insertar imagen y darle un aspecto deseado, yo utilizo éste código

```
Sub inserta_foto_imagen1()
    Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    myDocument.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="C:\Users\el.trasgu\Pictures\avestruz.jpg", _
    LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=200, Height:=200

    Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    myDocument.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="C:\Users\el.trasgu\Pictures\Sumiciu.jpg", _
    LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=300, Top:=100, Width:=100, Height:=150
End Sub
```

Lo que hago es:

seleciono de mi carpeta Imágenes la imagen avestruz.jpg
Luego la sitúo con un margen de 100 a la derecha desde el margen izquiero y 100 abajo desde el margen superior.
Luego le doy el tamaño de 200 x 200

seleciono de mi carpeta Imágenes la imagen Sumiciu.jpg
Luego la sitúo con un margen de 300 a la derecha desde el margen izquiero y 100 abajo desde el margen superior.
Luego le doy el tamaño de 100 x 150

Todo ello lo hago por medio de un botón de acción

Comment: Muchas gracias, asi mismo lo encontre y lo realize ahora estoy en busca de como agregarle un borde a la imagen y enviarla al fondo. sabes como puedo hacer esto?
con ZOrder msoSendToBack debiese irse al fondo la imagen pero no logro realizarlo

Comment: A que te refieres con enviarla al fondo, ponerla detrás de un texto por ejemplo pero a todo color, o como marca de agua

Comment: ponerla detras de un texto, y ponerle un borde de color negro por ejemplo a la imagen

Comment: Pues ahora mismo, no se responerte, voy a indagar. Por si acaso, abre una nueva pregunta de como poner bordes a una imagen en PowerPoint por si otros miembros de la comunidad conocen la solución. Un saludo

Comment: gracias, yo tambien estoy buscando y publique una nueva pregunta